# Iteration over table seems to not be working in python

Tags: python, iteration, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
table = [
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'], 
['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'], 
['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'], 
['v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
m = raw_input()
for row in table:
    for column in row:
        for letter in m:
            if letter == 'j':
                letter = 'i'
            if column == letter:
                print column
```

Which iterates over the alphabet, and checks each letter in the text provided, and if they match, prints out the current letter in the alphabet. My problem is that when passing `hello` to it, it prints out:

```
e
h
l
l
o
```

instead of:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

What is causing this? There are errors with several other examples of text, but not all. Is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: The problem is that you're iterating over the alphabet instead of the input, that's why the output characters are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: what is `if letter == 'j':` doing? also why are you storing the letters as a list of lists?

Comment: I guess he wants to print strings with i instead of j, and in future he will make some sort of ciphering machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected, printing the letters **in alphabetical order**. Just like what is in the table.

To print your output as received you need to iterate the user input **first**:

```
for letter in m: # this first
    for row in table:
        for column in row: 
            if letter == 'j':
                letter = 'i'
            if column == letter:
                print column
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) instead of a table?

If you want to check a string and replace `chr` inside it it will be much easier.

```
from string import maketrans

in_str = "i"
out_str = "j"
translate_in_out = maketrans(in_str, out_str)

m = raw_input()
print m.translate(translate_in_out, 'xm')
```

Comment: Actually, I was using this for something else, not just to replace the j, so I need all those loops.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine. Just instead of checking if letter is in your array, you checking if letter from array is in your word. You take first row, than first column (letter a) than check if letter a is == any letter in m. You need start form other side:

```
m = raw_input()
for letter in m:
  if letter == 'j'
    letter = 'i'
  for row in table:
    for column in row:
      if column == letter:
         print column
```

Comment: this is pretty much the same answer that has already been provided

Comment: Yes... it is the same, I was to slow. Should I delete my answer? The difference is in the explanation, why his code is not working. I believe I made it easier to understand.

Comment: @user3895596 you can comment on answers as well as questions :)

Comment: I just didn't know, there is another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the unwanted characters in `m`.

```
 m = m.replace('j', 'i')
```

Iterate *over* `m` and check if each character is `in` a table row.

```
for char in m:
    for row in table:
        if char in row:
            print char
```